# Svn fails on checkout with larger files

Tags: svn, apache, tortoisesvn

I'm having some problems with my Apache2 DAV Svn server. When I checkout my repository it gives me this error:

```
REPORT of '/svn/Mario_Kart_Source_Files/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: De externe host heeft een verbinding verbroken.
```

The translation from Dutch is: The external host has closed the connection
However, this only occurs when:

1. It is a "larger" file (Lets say > 1M)
2. I checkout from outside my own network. When I connect using localhost or from an other pc in my network, it works just fine.

I allready changed my timeouts in the httpd.conf, but it does not solve my problem.

```
DAVMinTimeout 1900
LimitXMLRequestBody 0
Timeout 1900
```

Does any of you know a solution to my problem?

Comment: Any upstream proxies? Routers? VPN's? Wireless? Do a tracert or traceoute to find out how many active netwerk components are involved in your netwotk path to the svn box

Comment: A Windows Server router is in between them. No wireless or VPN's. I did, however do a dump with Wireshark. Many rows come up as black with red text. Im a total noob with Wireshark though, so I don't know if thats good or bad.

Comment: What is running on the windows server for handling connections? IAS or whatever it is called nowadays?

Comment: I'ts called Routing and Remote Access (RRAS) for as far as I can see.

Comment: What version of Subversion client and server are you running? I am sure I had this problem myself, and that there is a bug in older versions of Subversion regarding this issue, but alas I can't find the link right now (so I may have mis-remembered it).

Comment: Just test once over a direct connection (UMTS for example) and you'll see if it's the HTTPd or router settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows router:

```
netsh routing ip nat set global tcptimeoutmins=60
```

That will set the timeout to be 60 minutes. Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754535%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_101 for more information.